# Behat fails runing after updating dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php, behat

Just updated composer on a functioning Behat, and now getting the following messages open running behat.

> PHP Deprecated:  "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper" is deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0.

Im using Behat-3 (~3.0@dev).

Any advice will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your composer.json looks like but I would suggest you to use stable versions for packages in require blocks. Try to use specific versions when possible.

```
"require": {
        "hello/world": "1.2.3",
        "abc/cde": "~4.3.0",
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    },
"require-dev": {
    "similar/to-above": "1.11"
},
"require-test": {
    "similar/to-above": "3.2.6"
},
```

Comment: Thanks @BentCoder, the symfony/console was downloading automatically  as part of requirement for other packages. so i just included `"symfony/console" : "v2.6.9"` (instead of the latest v2.7.0) and it solved the issue