# Symfony2 crash after composer update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I encounter a problem since I have update my vendors on Symfony2 installation.

This is content of my composer.json :

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "symfony/symfony": ">=2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": ">=1.2",
    "twig/extensions": ">=1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": ">=2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": ">=3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "@stable",
     "ornicar/akismet-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "appventus/alertify-bundle": "dev-master",
  "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "dev-master",
  "willdurand/propel-typehintable-behavior": "*",
  "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
  "nomaya/social-bundle": "dev-master"

}
}
```

After a `php composer.phar update`, when I try /app.php, I have following errors :

```
Deprecated: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface interface is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. in /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 3035
Deprecated: The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext class is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage or Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker instead. in /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 3047
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Catchable 
Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\Router::Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure}() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCacheInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache given' in /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1302 

Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/classes.php(1302): Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/var/www/html/p...', 1302, Array) 
#1 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache)) 
#2 /var/www/html/xxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/ConfigCacheFactory.php(46): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache)) 
#3 /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/classes.php(1313): Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCacheFactory->cache('/var/ww in /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 5261
```

and when I go to /app_dev.php I have this one :

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

 1/1
 FatalErrorException in ConfigDataCollector.php line 276:
 Error: Undefined class constant 'END_OF_MAINTENANCE'
```

My PHP Version is 5.6.9 on Apache/2.2.15.

Anyone have a clue ?

---

Thanks 
Knut

Comment: General advice. You should start using definite versions for each packages where possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728076/behat-fails-runing-after-updating-dependencies/30729506#30729506

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem by regenerating bootstrap.php.cache (by running composer update / composer install, or directly via script)

Comment: This solved the same problem for me. I used the following to recreate bootstrap.php.cache:
php ./vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

before

```
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was an incompatibility between my different vendors, I have updated my composer.json to :

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "symfony/symfony": ">=2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": ">=1.2",
    "twig/extensions": ">=1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": ">=2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": ">=3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": ">=2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "@stable",
     "ornicar/akismet-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "appventus/alertify-bundle": "dev-master",
  "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "dev-master",
  "willdurand/propel-typehintable-behavior": "*",
  "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
  "nomaya/social-bundle": "dev-master"

}
}
```

and all works ...

Thanks.

Comment: composer.json in this answer is identical to the one posted in question. Can you point out the change ? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
rm /var/www/html/xxx/app/cache/prod/* -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I encountered this issue after upgrading symfony (to 2.8 from 2.6) which was running on a vagrant guest.

The issue was indeed with the `app/bootstrap.php.cache` file. In our case, it was not excluded from our `rsync` which meant if the host had not also updated `composer` the problem would reoccur. It was solved by excluding `bootstrap.php.cache` from `rsync` in our Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.synced_folder "host/path", "guest/path", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: [ 'bootstrap.php.cache'],`

This file is generated by `composer`, so running `sudo composer install` or `sudo composer update` on the guest will regenerate it.

Hope this saves someone else some time.