# Error: Undefined class constant 'END_OF_MAINTENANCE' Symfony 2

Tags: php, git, symfony, caching

I'm developing the functions of an existing project.
The project is developed using Symfony 2. And I created a virtual host Apache (Ubuntu and LAMP) to turn it. When the boot gives me this error.
"FatalErrorException in ConfigDataCollector.php line 276: Error: Undefined class constant 'END_OF_MAINTENANCE'". I can not update the composer because if I would do when I would do after "git push" to the master should also load the new libraries (packages) and does not need it because the site run well with this version of the composer.
Then another thing:
it is normal that when I delete brutally cache symfony to understand (/ project / app / cache), when after loading the page of my project, Apache is to write with your permissions on the folder so I can not do php app / console cache: clear. I wanted to know if it is a problem that affects the other or not.
One other thing the same thing that happens to / project / app / cache happens with / project / app / logs.

I am attaching the composer.

```
    {
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "facebook/php-sdk": "3.2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "@stable",
    "mattketmo/email-checker": "~1.0",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
    "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "0.10.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775956/symfony2-crash-after-composer-update

Comment: I can't do composer update or install because after when I will do "git push"  in the server , git updates also vendor folder and vendor folder is correct and work in the server. It doesn't work only in my machine.

Comment: if you have another solution